# Join table with dates list - include reference on NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server

More brain freeze moments from me. I'm sure this will be an easy one.

I have two tables. One is a list of part usage by week. This is called TransactionsPerWeek and looks like this:

```
ItemPK       xWeek     xYear      TotalQty
1234         2         2019        65
1234         4         2019        15
1234         5         2019        50
```

I also have a DateList table that has week numbers and years in it

```
xWeek       xYear
 1          2019
 2          2019
 3          2019
```

etc.

When I right join the two together on week and year I get

```
ItemPK     xWeek    xYear    TotalQty
NULL        1       2019       0
1234        2       2019      65
NULL        3       2019       0
1234        4       2019      15
1234        5       2019      50
```

What I need is to have the ItemPK on every line, even if the TotalQty is 0. So in effect, I need:

```
ItemPK     xWeek    xYear    TotalQty
1234        1       2019       0
1234        2       2019      65
1234        3       2019       0
1234        4       2019      15
1234        5       2019      50
```

This is my code...

```
SELECT  itemfk,
        dates.year,
        dates.week,
        isnull(transactionsperweek.TotalQty,0) as TotalQty
from    (
            SELECT  iit.ItemFK,
                    year(iit.transactiondate) xYear,
                    datepart(wk,iit.transactiondate) xWeek,
                    abs(sum(iit.quantity)) TotalQty
            from    iteminventorytransaction iit
            INNER JOIN ItemInventoryTransactionType iitt on ItemInventoryTransactionTypePK = iit.ItemInventoryTransactionTypeFK
            where   iit.itemfk = 5311
                    and iit.ItemInventoryTransactionTypeFK in (10,8)
                    and iit.TransactionDate BETWEEN
                    -- 1 year up to the sunday of last week 
                    DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE()))
                    AND DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE())
                    AND Quantity < 0
            group by iit.itemfk,
                    year(iit.transactiondate),
                    datepart(wk,iit.transactiondate)
        ) transactionsPerWeek
RIGHT JOIN  (
                select  year,
                        week
                from    DatesList
                where   date > DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE()))
                        AND date < DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE())
                group by year,
                        week
            ) Dates ON dates.week = transactionsPerWeek.xWeek
                    AND dates.year = transactionsPerWeek.xYear
where   week not in (52,53)
```

Hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perform a `CROSS JOIN` between your `DateList` and your item table (which we don't have in the example) and the `LEFT JOIN` to `TransactionsPerWeek`.

Comment: isnull(transactionsperweek.TotalQty,0) should do the work. What do you see in TotalQty column for non-matching records?

Comment: @isidat I already have a isnull(transactionsperweek,TotalQty, 0) in my command. That is what gives the 0 value. It is the itemPK that I need to bring onto every record.

Comment: @David I thought the question is about how to select TotalQty as zero if there is no matching transaction in that month. If you want the same thing for ItemPK why don't you do the same? isnull(itemfk, '1234')

Comment: @isidat I need to show that the quantity for that week is 0 but there are no records for that week in the transactions table because there aren't any transactions, that's why I joined it to the dates table. But the dates table doesn't have itemfk in it.

Comment: @David Ok, it is the expected behavior, if there is no transaction, there should be no itemPK (which is primary key of transaction table) to be returned. Excuse me, I didn't get why you need itemPK value for the months not having any transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive cte :

```
with cte as (
     select 1 as id, max(xWeek) as maxwk
     from TransactionsPerWeek 
     union all
     select id + 1, maxwk
     from cte c
     where c.id < maxwk
)
select coalesce(wk.ItemPK, wk1.ItemPK) as ItemPK, c.id as xWeek, wk.xYear, wk.TotalQty
from cte c left join
     TransactionsPerWeek wk
     on wk.xWeek = c.id outer apply
     ( select top (1) wk1.ItemPK 
       from TransactionsPerWeek wk1
       where wk1.xWeek >= c.id and wk1.xWeek is not null
       order by wk1.xWeek
     ) wk1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did what @larnu suggested and cross joined the item with the dates, then left joined it to the transactionsperweek table and it worked. Thank you.

This is my code now;

```
SELECT itempk, week, year
, ISNULL(transactionsPerWeek.TotalQty,0) as TotalQty
from item
CROSS JOIN
(
        select year, week from DatesList where date > 
        DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE()))
        AND date <
        DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE())
        group by year, week
) dates

LEFT JOIN 

(
        SELECT iit.ItemFK, year(iit.transactiondate) xYear, datepart(wk,iit.transactiondate) xWeek, abs(sum(iit.quantity)) TotalQty from iteminventorytransaction iit
        INNER JOIN ItemInventoryTransactionType iitt on ItemInventoryTransactionTypePK = iit.ItemInventoryTransactionTypeFK
        where iit.itemfk = 5311 and iit.ItemInventoryTransactionTypeFK in (10,8)
        and iit.TransactionDate BETWEEN
        -- 1 year up to the sunday of last week 
        DateAdd(wk,-51,DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE()))
        AND
        DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,GETDATE())
        AND Quantity < 0
        group by iit.itemfk, year(iit.transactiondate), datepart(wk,iit.transactiondate)
    ) transactionsPerWeek
ON itempk = transactionsperweek.ItemFK and transactionsPerWeek.xYear = dates.year and transactionsPerWeek.xWeek = dates.week
where itempk = 5311
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the results you already have.

Your question explicitly states that you have two tables.  Hence, I don't know what your SQL code is doing, because it is not referencing those tables.  So, based on the description:

```
select i.ItemPK, d.xWeek, d.xYear,
       coalesce(TotalQty, 0) as TotalQty
from (select distinct itemPK from TransactionsPerWeek
     ) i cross join
     DateList d left join
     TransactionsPerWeek t
     on t.itemPK = i.itemPK and
        t.xWeek = d.xWeek and
        t.xYear = d.xYear;
```

Of course if the "tables" are really subqueries, then I would recommend using CTEs and still this basic query structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gordon. Yes, you're correct, they were actually sub-queries... i need to work on my descriptions on here. I managed to achieve what I needed using cross joins to create the rows and the left join to my other sub-query.